# UK Decision Making centre requesting Additional information/Documents

Tags: student-visa, uk-visa

I am applying for UK Student Visa ( Priority) and had given my Biometrics and documents for scanning on 13th of December. On 14th I received an email from the UK Decision Making Centre requesting 'additional' documents (Financial Documents, TB Certificate and All Education Qualifications), all of which I had scanned at VFS. I sent the requested documents on 14th to "SheffieldDocs.RequestedIndia@fco.gov.uk" and received an automated reply saying the documents have been received.

Does anyone have an idea why I was asked to send the same documents and how long a time it will take for me to get a decision?